# How can I join on a field(username) in the counts table to a student table where the username is part of a string in a field?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Counts table has: "trwal141" as username
Student table has: "cn=trwal141,ou=students,ou=cs,o=dvusd" as dn

I need to join on Counts.username [like or in] Student.dn to find user first and last names. Any suggestions. I'm not getting anything to work.

This is how I did the staff table join:

```
SELECT st.last, st.first, ct.Document, ct.PageCount, ct.Date, ct.DeviceID
FROM printer_stats.Counts ct
RIGHT JOIN dv.staff st on st.username = ct.username
WHERE ct.DATE >= "2011-10-30" and ct.DeviceID >0 
ORDER BY ct.DeviceID, st.last, st.first
```

Comment: How does dv.staff fit in?  is it the student table or are there three tables you're wanting to join?  Without writing the SQL yet, string manipulation could be used.  It looks like you're storing the AD fully qualified path.  So I'd either write a function to parse out the username, embed the string manipulation in the SQL, or modify the extract which is getting the LDAP info to pull out username and store it in a separate field.  I'll work on the inline SQL here...

Comment: xQbert - to anwser your question the dv.staff I use when the user is staff not a student. Differnt table for the student names than the staff names.

Answer (score 0):

Revised: the + 3 on the 2nd charindex was incorrect (darn copy and paste)

```
SELECT st.last, st.first, ct.Document, ct.PageCount, ct.Date, ct.DeviceID
FROM printer_stats.Counts ct
RIGHT JOIN dv.staff st on 
    substring(st.username,
    charindex('cn=',st.username,1)+3,
    charindex(',ou=',st.username,1)-charindex('cn='st.username,1)) = ct.username
WHERE ct.DATE >= "2011-10-30" and ct.DeviceID >0 
ORDER BY ct.DeviceID, st.last, st.first
```

Assumes the CN= denotes the start of a student
Assumes ,ou= will always FOLLOW the userid

I'm having to do this in ORACLE and translate to SQL server but here's the code in oracle that I know works:D

Select substr('cn=trwal141,ou=students,ou=cs,o=dvusd',
        instr('cn=trwal141,ou=students,ou=cs,o=dvusd','cn=',1)+3,
        instr('cn=trwal141,ou=students,ou=cs,o=dvusd'',ou=',1) - 
          instr('cn=trwal141,ou=students,ou=cs,o=dvusd','cn=',1))
FROM DUAL;

oracle substr = SQL 2008 SUBSTRING

oracle instr = SQl 2008 charindex

What the above basically does:

parces the "st.username field" finds the first instance of cn= and the first instance of ,ou= and gets the characters between them and treats that as the join criteria
From a performance stand point, you really should segregate the data; even if its a procedure you run to populate a temp table before you begin this type of query.

Comment: You will need to revise the above based on your comment ab out dv.staff.  but the process is similar  substring and charindex functions should give you everything you are after (but at the cost of performance)